# Position an iAd at bottom of screen (both orientations)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, iad

I have a Universal app (iPhone/iPad) testing on IOS4.3. It has an iAd which I want to position at the bottom of the screen in both the orientations..
Below is the code;

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
adView_.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects: ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait, ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape, nil];
    adView_.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;

    CGRect adFrame = adView_.frame;
    adFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height-adView_.frame.size.height;
    adView_.frame = adFrame;

    adView_.delegate = self;
    [webView addSubview:adView_];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:adView_];
    self.bannerIsVisible=NO;

    [super viewWillAppear: animated];
}
```

Now for orienation handling, I have;

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation))
        self.adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
    else
        self.adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
    CGRect adFrame = adView_.frame;
    adFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height-adView_.frame.size.height;
    adView_.frame = adFrame;
    [webView addSubview:adView_];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:adView_];
    self.bannerIsVisible=NO;
}
```

My issue is on app load (portrait), I am able to see the iAd clearly positioned at screen bottom.

But as soon as I change orientation to landscape, I cannot see the iAd. I see the message;

> ADBannerView: WARNING A banner view (0x62534a0) has an ad but may be
>   obscured. This message is only printed once per banner view.

I guess I am doing something wrong inside willRotateToInterfaceOrientation

Please help me fix the issue.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your code to didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation.  The new geometry is not set yet in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation.

Comment: The result is the same either using willRotateToInterfaceOrientation OR didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation ...Does the actual code inside those need to be changed somewhat ?